# Unix: Bash Limiting Output to X Amount of Lines

Tags: bash

I am trying to modify a script so that it will truncate the output that goes to another file  to a maximum (for example: 1000 lines).

I have read about split, but what I understand is that split by default does 1000 by default and splits that file into smaller files.

But, there may be a time when the output isn't going to be 1000 lines. It may only be 100.

I just want to cap the output at no more than X amount.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to split the output into multiple files, each limited to 1000 lines, then use `split`.

If you just want to "truncate the output that goes to another file to a maximum (for example: 1000 lines)," then use `head`:

```
cmd | head -n1000 >output_file
```

The `-n` option tells `head` to limit the number of lines of output.  Alternatively, to limit the output by number of bytes, the `-c` option would be used.  For details, see `man head`.

The companion utility to `head` is `tail`.  One uses `tail` when one wants the end of a file, rather the the beginning.  Thus, `tail -n1000` would deliver the last 1,000 lines of a file.